# search a value and replace d new value with the searched value

Tags: jquery, regex

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){     
   $(".blog").each(function()    
   {
       var text= $(this).html();
       text=text.replace(/@([a-z A-Z 0-9_]+)/ig,'<a href="#">([a-z A-Z 0-9_]+)</a>');
       $(this).html(text);
   });
 }) ;    
</script>
```

This is the HTML:

```
 <div class="blog">
 Lorem @Ipsum
 dolor#yeah</div>
```

Comment: Why is your HTML full of spaces? It drives me crazy.

Comment: I tried posting it with out space but it didn't post.

Comment: How did you write that HTML ?

Comment: This is pretty vague. Please be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish, what results you're getting, and how they differ from the desired results. (Please edit the question rather than responding in a comment)

Comment: FYI: `[a-z A-Z 0-9_]` could be rewrited `[\w ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the group reference in javascript using `$1`

```
text = text.replace(/@([a-z A-Z 0-9_]+)/ig,'<a href="#">$1</a>');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Vd3p/)